# Python pandas : dataframe read rows (readlines)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, readlines

I have a dataframe that was produced by pandas, for example:

```
d = {'one':[1,1],'two':[2,2], 'three':[3,3]}
i = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d, index = i)
df

        one two three

  a     1   2    3

  b     1   2    3

  c     1   2    3
```

I now need to read each row with comma separated, I don't want to save to_csv then open it again, any good suggestion?

I am used to something like in python:

```
for line in df.readlines():
    print line
```

But I don't know how to connect my ideas now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you wouldn't want to save and reopen but try this:

```
df = df.astype(str)
separators = pd.DataFrame(', ', df.index, df.columns[:-1])
separators[df.columns[-1]] = '\n'
print (df + separators).sum(axis=1).sum()

1, 3, 2
1, 3, 2
1, 3, 2
```